# erlide not compiling with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, erlang, erlide

I am able to run my code using my installation of erlang, but I want to integrate it into eclipse. I am having problems setting up the run configurations.  Below are screenshots of how I have the run configuration configured.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoiPW.jpg

The specific error message is:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching HelloWorldProject".
Expected the service to be RUNNING, but the service has FAILED
```

Comment: What runtime settings do you use (on the "runtime" tab)?

Comment: Readded the album with all the relevant tabs

Answer (score 0):

'erlide' as a name for the Erlang node is reserved (used by Erlide itself). Try another.  I will add a check for that and show a better error message.

Comment: Changed it from erlide to erlidetest and it works. Thank you!